# Passing different parameter to a method call depending on a condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the code for my function, in which I am making a call to `new`

```
def create_person_detail_from_registration(type, registration, registration_detail)
  person_detail = type.constantize.new(
    :email        => registration.email_2,
    :phone_1      => registration_detail.phone_1,
    :phone_2      => registration_detail.phone_2,
    :phone_3      => registration_detail.phone_3,
    :phone_4      => registration_detail.phone_4,
    :phone_5      => registration_detail.phone_5,
    :phone_6      => registration_detail.phone_6,
    :phone_7      => registration_detail.phone_7,
    :address_1    => registration_detail.address_1,
    :address_2    => registration_detail.address_2,
    :city         => registration_detail.city,
    :state        => registration_detail.state,
    :postal_code  => registration_detail.postal_code,
    :country      => registration_detail.country
  )
  return person_detail
end
```

Now the issue is depending on what value `type` has, `:email` is either set to `registration.email_2` or `registration.email`. One way of doing that is of course, to write the whole code twice surrounded by an `if-elsif` statement. But I just wanna know, if there's any smarter, more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the condition into value .

```
:email        => (type==1 ? registration.email_2 :  registration.email),
```

Comment: Is it possible to use an explicit if statement in this line, as this point in the code, when you're passing parameters to a method call?

Comment: You could always set the `email` attribute after having called `new`.

Comment: @Caffeine A ternary statement is an explicit conditional (though not an `if` statement, but that really shouldn't matter.)

Comment: @Caffeine : If you don't have use of type any more into method then just passed the the email (that you want to save) based on condition .

Comment: @Caffeine : If you get the time then accept & vote the answer :)

Comment: I tried doing that three times, each time SO told me Do it 6 minutes later, 3 minutes later, 1 minute later. Finally did that.